# New Windows, Linux systems keep hanging

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I had a Windows-Kali Linux dual boot system on a 500 gig hard disk - Windows 150G, Kali 120G and then separated the remaining partitions evenly to two. This plan was working perfectly.

I formated and deleted all these partitions and repartitioned the hard-disk: Windows 80G, Kali 30G. It is impossible to work with the systems as they keep hanging. I've tried these other options:

> Deleted all the partitions and only had one partition on which I installed Windows, but this did not help. It still keeps hanging. I even tried having only Kali on on the whole 500G, but still the system still is unusable since it keeps hanging every other time on every new mouse event, be it on link clicks within browser web pages or on clicking buttons on a program's window, or on clicking on tool bar items.

Start up used to take 15 - 30 secs. Now it takes 7 - 10 minutes.

What could be the problem? Why are the systems hanging?

Thank you all in advance.

I've tried:

1. Windows 10,
2. Kali Linux,
3. Ubuntu,
4. Fedora

**UPDATE**

I did a S.M.A.R.T check on my hard-disk, but I'm not sure how to interpret the results. This is what came up:

```
user@user-HP-650-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.10.0-33-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABF...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
Serial Number:    5374C6ZFT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 4c3482dc5
Firmware Version: AM002C
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Sep  3 18:00:18 2017 EAT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 101) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   098   098   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1376
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23263
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       184
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       6419
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   253   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3425
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       3545
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       85
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   056   039   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 44 (Min/Max 43/49 #8)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1045
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30933464
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       52547
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   056   039   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 44 (Min/Max 43/49 #8)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15736
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 4214 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4214 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6294 hours (262 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 58 c0 5d 54 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00545dc0 = 5529024

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 60 8f 5e 54 40 00      02:56:26.131  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 58 8f 5d 54 40 00      02:56:26.131  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:26.130  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 50 8e 5e 54 40 00      02:56:22.331  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:22.330  READ LOG EXT

Error 4213 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6294 hours (262 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 50 8e 5e 54 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00545e8e = 5529230

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 50 8e 5e 54 40 00      02:56:22.331  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:22.330  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 50 8e 5e 54 40 00      02:56:18.520  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 48 8e 5d 54 40 00      02:56:18.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:18.519  READ LOG EXT

Error 4212 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6294 hours (262 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 48 c0 5d 54 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00545dc0 = 5529024

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 50 8e 5e 54 40 00      02:56:18.520  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 48 8e 5d 54 40 00      02:56:18.519  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:18.519  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 40 8d 5e 54 40 00      02:56:14.719  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:14.718  READ LOG EXT

Error 4211 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6294 hours (262 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 40 8d 5e 54 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00545e8d = 5529229

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 40 8d 5e 54 40 00      02:56:14.719  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:14.718  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 40 8d 5e 54 40 00      02:56:10.908  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 8d 5d 54 40 00      02:56:10.908  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:10.907  READ LOG EXT

Error 4210 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6294 hours (262 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 38 c0 5d 54 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00545dc0 = 5529024

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 40 8d 5e 54 40 00      02:56:10.908  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 8d 5d 54 40 00      02:56:10.908  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:10.907  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 30 8c 5e 54 40 00      02:56:07.108  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:56:07.107  READ LOG EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      5570         272179816
# 2  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%      3117         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       292         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         2         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

user@user-HP-650-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidPostill. I did a S.M.A.R.T check on my hard-disk, but I'm not sure how to interpret the results. I did an update to the question with what came up. I, however have problems interpreting the results. Could you please help. Thank you again.

Comment: You have read errors, and reallocated sectors. You should keep an eye on the reallocated sectors as it is an indication of disk failure if it goes up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidPostill. Is there a possible fix for read errors, and reallocated sectors? Could this be what is causing the problems I'm having?

Comment: If there are problems reading the disk then that can explain the symptoms you are seeing. The reallocated sectors **are** the fix. There is nothing more you can do. If the disk is failing more sectors will be reallocated (and there is a limit to the reserved space for this).